# why is innerclass's overridden method automatically invoked?

Tags: java, class, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing doubly linked list and below is my code segment.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {

private Node head = null;
private Node tail = null;
private int size = 0;

private class Node{

    private Object data;
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;

    private Node(Object input) {
       this.data = input;
       this.next = null;
       this.previous = null;
    }// Node.Constructor

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.data);
    }

  }// class Node

  public Node node(int k) {
      Node x = head;
      for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
         x = x.next;
      }
    return x; 
  }// DoublyLinkedList.node
}// class DoublyLinkedList

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DoublyLinkedList l = new DoublyLinkedList();
    l.addFirst(3);
    l.addFirst(4);
    l.addFirst(5);
    l.addFirst(6);
    System.out.println(l.node(0));
    System.out.println(l.node(1));
    System.out.println(l.node(2));
    System.out.println(l.node(3));
}
```

in this code, without toString method in Node class, node method returns the address of kth node. However, with this toString method, it returns the data kth node includes though I've never called this method. why is this method in innnerclass automatically called?

Comment: `String.valueOf(this.data)` calls `this.data.toString()`

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "address of kth node" and "the data kth node includes"? Or more simply said: What output are you getting and what about it confuses you?

Comment: @Eran that return statement is in a method and I never called that method. when is toSting method exactly called?

Comment: You didn't show the code that uses your class, so I can't say. You must have some print statement somewhere.

Comment: Can you add the caller method to the example? The **node(k)** method always returns an object with __Node__ type, otherwise the code would not compile. Defining the **toString** method in Node class will override the **Object.toString**, even without the @Override annotation. The caller function may implicitly invoke Object.toString(), which will cause Node.toString() to be executed.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS method 'node' gets int k and returns the address of  'kth' node but with method 'toString' in Node class, it returns the data it has. The problem is that I never called method 'toStiring'. I do not get it why node method returns the data that node has, not the address of it simply because I declared toString method. Sorry for my poor English:0

Comment: Also remember that often a debugger will call an objects `toString` method.

Comment: @JUNTAE That leads to a question, where you see it "printed"? Provide code sample or share more details ;-)

Comment: We see the misuderstanding now - `l.node` correctly returns Node instance, but what do you expect `System.out.println` will do with that... You can see the code in Java implementation - it calls `String.valueOf()` to handle null case also...

Comment: @Gábor oh, I didn't know that. I renamed my method and it worked as I intended. but still, I do not get :(

Comment: @JUNTAE in Java all classes are ultimatley the child class of the Object class. The println method calls Object.toString() to print the value of its parameter. When you define a method named exactly as __toString__ with zero parameters, then as per Java syntax you are overriding that method in Object (in your case it effectively means that your code will be executed instead of the one defined in Object class). This subject is quite important in Java development. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in debugger or modify your code a bit, to see what's going on...

```
DoublyLinkedList l = new DoublyLinkedList();
l.addFirst(3);
Node n0 = l.node(0)
System.out.println(n0);
```

and implementation for `System.out.println(Object obj)` is

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

and `String.valueOf(Object obj)` is

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

...and that calls your `toString()` (if defined) or default one from `java.lang.Object` class

Answer (score 1):

`Object#toString()` has defined in Object class so if you are not overriding toString then it will invoke the Object#toString(), and see how it looks like in object class.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So by default, it will return HexString of `hasCode` concatenated with the class name. But when you override `toString` in Node class `Node#toString` invoked.